# System Center Endpoint Protection remote scan

Tags: system-center, endpoint

Could I use psexec to start a remote scan of a clients System Center Endpoint Protection ? I can't find any switches. Or Could I use System Center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use whatever remote execution tool you want.

You want to run `c:\program files\Microsoft Security Client\MPCmdRun.exe -Scan 0`

Run it without any parameters to see all the options - you can choose what scan level (0 is default), force it to update antivirus signatures, gather files for support logs, etc.

Comment: Thanks. The only concern I have is that this .exe is for Windows defender right? Not system security end point? I need system security to run the scan please.

Comment: @benjaminjones it is part of SCEP.  The same exe is probably used in defender and security essentials because they are all based on the same code, but this is definitely part of endpoint protection.

Comment: Great thanks. Do you know how I can create a log file for the scan? .-getfile is not producing a log file.